# Multisession odometry

Tags: slam, lidar, odometry

I have two bag files with significant overlap and multiple loop closure opportunities. However, these bag files were recorded at different times. I want to use these bag files to reconstruct a scene and chain the reconstructions together. Currently, I am using fastlio with scancontext.

However, when I run the second bag file in the same fastlio session, the reconstruction breaks, possibly due to imu initialization issues. If I keep the scancontext session and restart the fastlio session, the reconstruction gets placed at 0,0,0, and scancontext cannot find a proper match.

Can anyone suggest a workflow for chaining the reconstructions together using multi-session data and bag files with significant overlap? How can I avoid these initialization issues in fastlio and maintain the proper placement of the reconstruction using scancontext?

I would also like to ask if there are alternative solutions for using Livox LiDARs (Mid-360) and offline SLAM to chain reconstructions together with multi-session bag file data.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a while, the best repo I have found for offline reconstruction/pose graph optimization and merging multisession data is interactive slam. https://github.com/SMRT-AIST/interactive_slam

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the graph optimization approach?

1. Cut the fastlio local map into segments
2. Generate a pose graph from the segments
3. Repeat 1,2 for the other dataset
4. Run a place recognition algorithm like BoW3D or scancontext to find the correspondence between the segments
5. Find the 6 dof transformations between the matchings
6. Add them to the graph
7. Run the optimization